# exchange 2010 - updating distribution list members via outlook address book

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, exchange-2010, outlook

I'm having trouble updating distribution list memberships using outlook.

on exchange 2010:
groups properties - group information
I have added myself to the managed by list

in active directory (server 2008)
my account is set to the name under the managed by tab inside the groups properties
I have also given myself full control under the security tab in the a/d properties

However,

- In outlook if I go to tools
- addressbook double click the group
- modify members

  I am told that i do not have sufficient permissions to perform the action

anyone have any idea why this may be ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that is actually a bug that is worked around by using the `Manage-GroupManagementRole.ps1` script. It can be found [here](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/8c22734a-b237-4bba-ada5-74a49321f159). You can read more about the issue [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2009/11/18/3408844.aspx).

Comment: Figures. I ran the script that they posted - following the directions on the blog post but it didn't seem to fix my issue. it did change the 'manage group membership' check box under the managed by tab in active directory - but still tells me that i have insufficient privileges to make the changes

Comment: Did you restart outlook? Do you have Cache Exchange Mode turned on, when updating stuff, I loath that setting.

Comment: I did restart outlook - but cached exchange mode is turned on for my outlook.

Comment: restarting exchange seemed to correct the issue (after the script was run) thanks for your help

Comment: Glad that did the trick for you!